# how to make processes and they do different assign tasks for example doing reading from a file or writing to a file using fork

Tags: c++, linux, operating-system, signals, fork

How to make processes and they do different assign tasks. I have written the code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
int status=0;
{
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
if(fork()==0)
{ cout<<"do some thing"<<endl; }
else

{wait(status); }


}

return 0;
}
```

This code creates 5 processes but all will do same thing. I want them to do different tasks

Answer (score 0):

use parameter 'i' .. the newly fork'd process can use case or if-then-else to invoke unique function per process.

Example:

```
  uint32_t spinTillTime0SecChange(void)
  {
     uint32_t spin_count = 1; // time(0) invocation count

     // no measurement, just spinning
     time_t t0 = time(0);
     time_t t1 = t0;

     while (t0 == t1)
     {
        t1 = time(0);
        spin_count += 1;
        DTB::msPause(10);  // uses usleep()
     }
     return(spin_count);
  }


  void child0(int i)
  {
     std::cout << "child0() start " << std::endl;
     int k = 0;
     time_t t0 = time(0) + 10; // spin for 10 seconds
     do {
        std::cout << "child0() " << i << "." << k++ << std::endl;
        (void)spinTillTime0SecChange();
        if (time(0) == t0) break;
     }while(1);
     exit(0);   // do not return
  }

  void child1(int i)
  {
     std::cout << "child1() start " << std::endl;
     int k = 0;
     time_t t0 = time(0) + 10; // spin for 10 seconds
     do {
        std::cout << "child1() " << i << "." << k++ << std::endl;
        (void)spinTillTime0SecChange();
        if (time(0) == t0) break;
     }while(1);
     exit(0);   // do not return
  }

  void child2(int i)
  {
     std::cout << "child2() start " << std::endl;
     int k = 0;
     time_t t0 = time(0) + 10; // spin for 10 seconds
     do {
        std::cout << "child2() " << i << "." << k++ << std::endl;
        (void)spinTillTime0SecChange();
        if (time(0) == t0) break;
     }while(1);
     exit(0);   // do not return
  }

  void child3(int i)
  {
     std::cout << "child3() start " << std::endl;
     int k = 0;
     time_t t0 = time(0) + 10; // spin for 10 seconds
     do {
        std::cout << "child3() " << i << "." << k++ << std::endl;
        (void)spinTillTime0SecChange();
        if (time(0) == t0) break;
     }while(1);
     exit(0);   // do not return
  }

  void child4(int i)
  {
     std::cout << "child4() start " << std::endl;
     int k = 0;
     time_t t0 = time(0) + 10; // spin for 10 seconds
     do {
        std::cout << "child4() " << i << "." << k++ << std::endl;
        (void)spinTillTime0SecChange();
        if (time(0) == t0) break;
     }while(1);
     exit(0);   // do not return
  }


  int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv[]*/ )
  {
     uint32_t retVal = 0;

     std::cout << std::endl;

     for (int i = 0; i<5; ++i)
     {
        pid_t childPID = fork();

        if(childPID == 0) // when 0 returned: child context
        {
           switch (i) // from loop, choose what this child will run
           {
           case 0: { child0(i); } break;
           case 1: { child1(i); } break;
           case 2: { child2(i); } break;
           case 3: { child3(i); } break;
           case 4: { child4(i); } break;

           default:
           {
              std::cerr << "out of range i: " << i << std::endl;
              DTB::msPause(10); // uses usleep
           }
           break;

           } // switch (i)
        }

        dtbAssert(childPID >= 0)(childPID); // error check
     }

     // parent context
     std::cout << "parent() context after fork" << std::endl;
     int k = 0;
     time_t t0 = time(0) + 13; // spin for 13 seconds
     do {
        std::cout << "parent() " << " " << " " << k++ << std::endl;
        (void)spinTillTime0SecChange();
        if (time(0) == t0) break;
     }while(1);

     return(retVal);
  }
```

Comment: Note that in the sample code, the childX() function does not return.  This prevents the child from forking additional processes.

Comment: Note that each process is independent of each other.  You will probably want to investigate the various IPC's to make these processes cooperate.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is to check the value returned by the fork function, it will be equal to 0 in the child and to the process ID of the child in the parent process. You can use this fact to structure your code as follows:

```html
if (fork() == 0)  //Fork a child
{
  //Put child 1 code here

  return 0;
}

if (fork() == 0)  //Fork a child
{
  //Put child 2 code here

  return 0;
}

if (fork() == 0)  //Fork a child
{
  //Put child 3 code here

  return 0;
}

if (fork() == 0)  //Fork a child
{
  //Put child 4 code here

  return 0;
}

if (fork() == 0)  //Fork a child
{
  //Put child 5 code here

  return 0;
}
```

Notice that it doesn't make sense here to put it in a for loop because each child will have its own different code, but if you want to make the thing fit in a for loop then you should consider reading about the ***exec*** functions and placing the codes that you want in different programs.

Best of luck